# Supporting both github.com and github enterprise in Devise logins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm building a Rails application that normally authenticates against a local Github Enterprise installation when logging in users. I would like to enable logged-in users to associate their `github.com` ID to their account on my application, but struggle to figure out how to do this.

Specifically, the problem is that both authentication methods would use the `github` authentication strategy in the `omniauth` set up. However, the relevant `OAUTH` urls as well as my internal callback controller need to be different for each case (in one case, I actually want to do a login, in the other case, I simply want to add more information to the `current_user`). Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, I can only configure the `github` strategy once, but I need to set up two different configurations for the two different providers.

I have been searching through the Devise and Omniauth documentation for some time now, but without success. Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely here? If not, can somebody point me in the right direction, please?

Many thanks,

Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the `devise` sources, I found a reasonably straightforward solution. The central problem is how to get `devise` to use the same `omniauth` strategy twice, but with different API and callback URLs. So we need to register two instances of `omniauth-github`  under two different provider IDs **and** names. To make this work, you need to explicitly give the strategy class name in the second instantiation. So, all together you get something like this:

```
# Github Enterprise login through standard github provider
config.omniauth :github,
                Rails.configuration.ghe_oauth_id,
                Rails.configuration.ghe_oauth_secret,
                client_options: {
                  site: 'https://github-enterprise/api/v3',
                  authorize_url: 'https://github-enterprise/login/oauth/authorize',
                  token_url: 'https://github-enterprise/login/oauth/access_token'
                },
                scope: 'user repo'

# Github.com support using the same strategy, but with a different provider ID and name
config.omniauth :github_com,
                Rails.configuration.github_com_oauth_id,
                Rails.configuration.github_com_oauth_secret,
                strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::GitHub,
                name: :github_com,
                scope: 'user repo'
```

The route setup remains the same as with a single `omniauth` provider. In my callbacks-controller for `devise` callbacks, I now have a method `github` for handling authentication through Github Enterprise and one `github_com` for github.com authentication.